# Why isn't the thymeleaf object recognized?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

The first code snipped is me adding(or rather trying) the attribute 'NewUser' to use in html.

The error pops up for 'th:field="*{name}"'.

Error:
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'

```
@RequestMapping("home")
public String newUser(Model model) {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setId(100l);
    newUser.setName("Test");
    newUser.setEmail("test@what.com");
    newUser.setPermission(0);
    model.addAttribute(newUser);
    return "index";
}

<form action="#" th:action="@{/home/add}" th:object="${newUser}" method="get">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{permission}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You might try using th:object="${user}" I believe when Model.addAttribute is called with no attributeName argument it uses the name of the class in lowercase

Comment: Sadly it doesn't change anything, same error same line.

Comment: I agree with Josh Van de Walle.  Thymeleaf can't find that object.  Either you're not naming it correct (e.g. you should doing this `model.addAttribute("newUser", newUser);` instead of `model.addAttribute(newUser);`) or you are on the wrong controller and the object isn't being added at all.  [See this (my code is the same as yours except I'm naming my attribute)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmrlY.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause is you didn't create the **getter method** for the fileds: **name**, **email**, and **permission**. So, when the **thymeleaf** try to **render the page**, it cannot **read the value** of the name field, or email field, or permission field.

Comment: Ah, I do actually have the getter methods set, so I guess that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding another model and it seems like it was causing issues, so I ended up doing this and everything is working fine.

The 'userList' model is used elsewhere in the code.

```
@GetMapping("home")
public String index(Model model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("userList", userService.getUsers());
    return "index";
}

<form th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/home/add}" method="get">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{permission}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input/></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help someone...the issue is that you didn't provide the model  that thymleaf  will use to map your form input value. so you just  have to pass as parameter  "user model" like that .....

```
public String newUser(User model) {
 
}
```

.....thymleaf  will use it to map your form field ...it work fine for me